# Swift: Expected declaration error in if statement

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller

I have a `TableViewController` and a `ViewController`. I am trying to link the two together and print a certain statement in the `ViewController` dependent on which row has been tabbed in the `TableViewControler`.

I declared a public variable called `rowCounter` and in the `TableViewController` class I set `rowCounter` equal to the row of the `indexPath`.

Then, in the `TableViewController` I am trying to use an if-statement to access the `rowCounter` variable and print a statement dependent on the number but I keep getting an 'expected declaration' error. What am I doing wrong?

Here's the code:

`TableViewController`:

```
import UIKit

var rowCounter: Int = 0

class TableTableViewController: UITableViewController {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Uncomment the following line to preserve selection between presentations
    // self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = false

    // Uncomment the following line to display an Edit button in the navigation bar for this view controller.
    // self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem()
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, willSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> NSIndexPath? {

    rowCounter = indexPath.row

    return indexPath
}
```

`ViewController`:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

if rowCounter == 1 {

println("test")

}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

}
```

Answer (score 8):

```
if rowCounter == 1 {

println("test")

}
```

is outside the func